# Problema ao fechar menu

Tags: javascript

Bom dia pessoal, tudo bem com vcs?

Estou com um problema que não consigo achar a solução de maneira nenhuma (sou leigo com o JS ainda). É o seguinte, tenho um menu OffCanvas que abre ao clicar no ícone de hambúrguer, consigo fazer ele abrir e fechar, mas eu queria que ao clicar fora do menu ele também fechasse, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso, quando penso em uma lógica, para de abrir e fechar o menu. Segue o código JS

```
const open_menu = document.getElementById('js-open-button');
const close_menu = document.getElementById('js-close-button');

open_menu.addEventListener('click', OnCanvas );
close_menu.addEventListener( 'click', OffCanvas);
var abriu = false;

// Ao clicar no ícone de hambúrguer , abre o menu
function OnCanvas() {
    if(!abriu) {
        document.body.classList.add('show-menu');
        abriu = true;
    }
}

// Ao clicar no X fecha o menu
function OffCanvas() {
    if(abriu) {
        document.body.classList.remove('show-menu');
        abriu = false;
    }
}
```

O HTML que estou utilizando

```
<!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
<div class="offCanvas">
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="icon-list">
      <!-- Form Search -->
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn search-button-icon" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
      <!-- End Form Search -->

      <!-- Navbar -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> INÍCIO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- End Navbar -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <button class="close-button" id="js-close-button">Close Menu</button>
</div>
<!-- End Off Canvas Menu -->
<div class="content-wrap">
  <div class="js-content">
    <header>
      <!-- Head Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-header" id="navbarNav">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <!-- Toggle Button -->
          <button class="menu-button d-block d-xl-none d-lg-none" id="js-open-button" type="button" >
            <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>
          <!-- Toggle Button End -->
        
          <!-- Logo -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img class="img-fluid" width="130" src="./assets/images/logo_imperial.svg" alt="Logo Imperial">
          </a>
          <!-- End Logo -->

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-end">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">INÍCIO</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End Navbar -->

            <!-- Form Search -->
            <form class="d-flex" id="search-form">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar..." aria-label="Pesquisar">
              <button class="btn search-button-icon" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
            <!-- End Form Search -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- End Head Navbar -->
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desde já agradeço :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente tem que registar o click event no body do documento e verificar se o elemento clickado está dentro do offcanvas. Isto traduz-se numa função recursiva `isElementInOffCanvas` que verifica se um determinado elemento (e os seus elementos pai) têm a classe `offCanvas`.

Simplifiquei um pouco a sua lógica, nomeadamente removendo a flag `abriu` e utilizando `classList.toggle` para controlar a visibilidade do menu.

Por favor verifique o seguinte código.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) { bodyClick(e); });
document.getElementById('js-open-button').addEventListener('click', toggleOffCanvas);
document.getElementById('js-close-button').addEventListener('click', toggleOffCanvas);

function bodyClick(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('open-button')) return;

  if (!isElementInOffCanvas(e.target)) {
    document.body.classList.remove('show-menu');
  }
}

function isElementInOffCanvas(element) {
  if (element.classList && element.classList.contains('offCanvas')) return true;

  return (element.parentNode && isElementInOffCanvas(element.parentNode)) || false;
}

function toggleOffCanvas() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('show-menu');
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.offCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: -100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 216px;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}

.show-menu .offCanvas {
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="open-button" id="js-open-button">Open Menu</button>

  <div class="offCanvas">
    <nav class="menu">
      <div class="icon-list">
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn search-button-icon" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Início</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <button class="close-button" id="js-close-button">Close Menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Top mano, muito obrigado!!
Só está acontecendo um problema estranho, no meu botão para abrir o menu, eu coloquei um ícone do Font Awsome, só que se eu coloco a classe "open-button" no botão, ao clicar no icone não funciona e vice versa e se eu coloco nos dois, o do ícone não funciona. Saberia me dizer o que está ocorrendo?

Comment: À partida diria para colocar nos dois. É apenas uma classe para controlo no javascript, não se destina a associar nenhum css.

Comment: Basta pressionar o "check" no início da sua pergunta. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) explica melhor como o fazer.